# Show Edit.Parameterinfo in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio

In Visual Studio you have a shortcut for **Edit.ParameterInfo** and that is CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE.
In Xamarin Studio the shortcut is the same when you look in the options of the IDE.
But the problem is when I set my caret inside the brakets and press the desired shortcut, the Parameterinfo just appears in a specific case: when my caret is exactly after the bracket or a comma.
If there is a space or more between my caret and the bracket, the tooltip won't show up.
Has anybody any experience about that, because in VS it is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current version of Xamarin Studio ParameterInfo is only working right after brackets and commas as you noticed. [I fixed this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/pull/392) today and should be in next release ;)